# Excel start new page printing when column b change value

Tags: excel, excel-2007

Are there any functions or methods that start a new page printing when column b is changed?

For example, as column b changes value from David to Robert start a new page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean
but the following code will print the worksheet when user changes a cell of column B

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.PrintOut
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edit After Comment**

So this is what you need:

```
Sub PaginateBasedOnColB()
    Dim lngRowsCount As Long
    Dim lngCounter As Long

    lngRowsCount = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    MsgBox lngRowsCount

    For lngCounter = 1 To lngRowsCount

        If ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lngCounter, 2) <> _
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(lngCounter + 1, 2) Then
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add (ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & lngCounter + 1))
        End If

    Next lngCounter
End Sub
```

Comment: It like this I have a bout 30000 rows of excel when i want to print a sheet I want to start new pages when lo cation is change such as

Comment: row 100 columb is new york when row 101 column b is Washington  how can i make it sart new page

Comment: Add the new code into the VBA code of your sheet and press F5 inside Sub